# Curved corners on a popup.html?

Tags: html, google-chrome, css, google-chrome-extension

I'm wondering how I curve the corners of the popup.html page on a Chrome extension? I've tried... http://borderradius.com/ entering 10 for all cornors and putting that in the body of my CSS but it doesn't seem to work. Is there a special way I have to style it?

Answer (score 5):

Do you mean this whole popup container? It's not possible.

You can right click on a popup icon and select "Inspect popup" and then play with css in the inspector - you will see that popup container itself is out of reach (its some system GUI element probably).

Comment: Seems like this is still correct :/